# insert update delete and select in the same view mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

simply i want to insert update delete and show in the same view in mvc 4 Razor ?
is the solution just many partial view in the same view ?
All of yours suggestions are helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform all basic insert,update and delete *actions* in same index view.

**For Create**

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
"CreateText", 
"CreateMethod", 
"ControllerName",
new { id = item.EntityId}, 
new AjaxOptions { @UpdateTargetId = "CreateDivId" }) //create div in view and assign id to it so that edit form will appear there on click.
```

**For Edit**

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
"EditText", 
"EditMethod",
"ControllerName" 
new { id = item.EntityId}, 
new AjaxOptions { @UpdateTargetId = "EditDivId")  //create div in view and assign id to it so that edit form will appear there on click.
```

**For Delete**

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
"DeleteText", 
"DeleteMethod",
"ControllerName" 
new { id = item.EntityId}, 
new AjaxOptions { @UpdateTargetId = "DeleteDivId" }) //create div in view and assign id to it so that edit form will appear there on click.
```

Comment: thaaaaaannnnnkkkkkssss